# Update a list which is a value to a key in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary like:

```
d = {c1: l1, c2: l2, c3: l3, ......., cn: ln}
```

where c1, c2,.... cn are strings and l1, l2,... l3 are lists.

Now, I have a function where the list needs to be updated, for a pair of variables c, x:

**1. if c is in d:**

Find the (key, value) for c, and update the corresponding l with x

**2. if c not in d:**

Create a cm: lm pair in d

So far, what I've tried is:

```
if c in d:
    d.update({cn:ln.append(x)})
else:
    d.update({cm:lm.insert(x)})
```

But the code isn't working as expected.

Any pointers as to why the code not working would be helpful, and any suggestions for the code which can make it work are welcome.

P.S: The c and x values are passed as arguments to a function, where all the updating happens.

For clarification, I'm running Python 2.7, on PyCharm, on Windows 10.

Edit:

[image: A sample output]

Comment: A sample output would be delightful.

Comment: `dict.update` is the wrong tool for the job. You want to update a *list*, not the *dict*. And neither `list.append` nor `list.insert` return a new list; both them return `None`.

Comment: `if c in d..d[c].append(x);else..d[c].insert(index, x)` ?

Comment: Yep @Aran-Fey, got None as the value after update and insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if c in d:
    # d[c] corresponds to the list you want to update
    d[c].append(x)
    # the append function directly modifies the list at d[c], 
    # so we don't have to do any re-assignment
else:
    # d[c] does not exist, so we create a new list with your item
    d[c] = [x]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see https://repl.it/repls/ExternalCornyOpendoc
Example code as below:

```
d = {
  "Key1":[1,2,3],
  "Key2":[11,12,13]
}

def test(c, x):
  if c in d:
    d[c].append(x);
  else:
    d[c] = [x];
  print(d)

test("Key1", 12)
test("Key3", 122)
```